# How to start voting for maps?

Tags: counter-strike-source

How can I start voting for a map in Counter-Strike: Source?

Comment: Does the server have any plugins?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert CS:S player, but I'll take a shot at answering your question.

According to [this post](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2602422) on the Steam community forums, the command to call a vote is:
`callvote changelevel mapname`. It does look like servers can disable the call vote command, so you might not be able to use the command on all servers. Good luck!

Comment: It also sais that the command is bugged and you can't buy anything in the buy menu. You'll need a buy script.

Comment: Only one user in the thread reported that, and another said it worked perfectly fine. YMMV

Comment: Just to be cautious.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you want to change the map. If you're a player on a random server then mostly `!rtv` or `rtv`, `!callvote` or `callvote`, `!changemap` or `changemap` are the most common ways to start a vote on public servers (depends on how they are configured).

If you have your own server running and you're able to input commands into the Console then `changelevel "mapname"` is the right command, but you need admin rights for that.